# How to display two inner divs at the bottom of an outer div

Tags: html, css

I have a outer div which has two inner divs. The second inner div may or may not contain text value. Currently the two inner divs are displayed at the top. However I want to be displayed always at the bottom. The divs are shown below:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="firstInnerDiv"></div>
  <div class="secondInnerDiv"></div>
<div>
```

I tried to add position:absolute;bottom:0 to both the inner divs. Then both disappear. I tried vert-align:bottom at the outer div, which has no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `position:relative;` to your outer div and inner divs and `position:absolute;` to your inner wrapper (`.inner`), That would do it!

```css
.outerDiv{
  position:relative;
  width:100px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.inner{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
.firstInnerDiv, .secondInnerDiv{
  width:100px;
  height:auto;
}
.firstInnerDiv{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.secondInnerDiv{
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">Main
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="firstInnerDiv">Div 1</div>
    <div class="secondInnerDiv">Div 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It kind of works! The only issue I have is that, when the secondInnerDiv doesn't have any value, it still occupies a height of 50px. is there any way the value in the firstInnerDiv moves all the way down when the secondInnerDiv  is empty? Thanks

Comment: you can change height:50px; to height:auto; and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Position Of Parant Div Is Should Give "Relative" And Give Position Absolute To InnerDivs.

```css
.outerDiv{
  position:relative;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid #ff8800;
}
.firstInnerDiv{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:105px;
  border:1px solid red;
  bottom:-110px;
}
.secondInnerDiv{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:105px;
  border:1px solid red;
  bottom:-215px;
  
}

This Is Example Of Your Requirement Try Once .
```

```html
<div class="outerDiv">This IS Main Div
  <div class="firstInnerDiv">Inner One</div>
  <div class="secondInnerDiv">Inner Two</div>
<div>
```

Comment: Sorry, may be I was not clear in describing the question. The inner divs should be one over the other and not side by side. Thanks

Comment: K. No Problem I Updated My Ans Check Once .

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned elements will be positioned in relation to the closest parent that is positioned. If none are positioned, they will be positioned in relation to the . If you give `.outerDiv` a CSS of `position: relative;` and then position the inner elements absolutely, then you should get the results you're looking for. You can read more on positioning [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).